# Integer vs String field mysql design approach for php web

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with products that contains 2 fields.

1)id of the product int-7digits

2)name of the product

The name of the product can only be 27 different values like banana,apple etc

Now im wondering what is the best approach for my web-server resources.
I mean i should use 1,2,3,... values or string values?

~Edit my table will be about 1million rows and steadily increasing over time.

Comment: _Now im wondering what is the best approach for my web-server resources. I mean i should use 1,2,3,... values or string values?_ in which field... `product name` ??

Comment: The approach depends upon the usage of the field.. Whether you want to fetch the value and print it to somewhere or just need some comparison or similar kinda thing.. hope you got the point..

Comment: You can use "ENUM" type ,If you know the 27 exact values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `VARCHAR` for the name field, for readability. If you have to come back to this in 9 months and remember if 1 is an apple or a banana, you're going to struggle a lot.

As I assume you have to print out product names, you're basically choosing between selecting strings in PHP or MySQL. Either `SELECT * FROM fruit WHERE product_name = 'Banana'` or `SELECT * FROM fruit where product = 7` and then `foreach($fruits as $fruit): if $fruit['id'] = $row['product'] { return $fruit['name']; } endforeach;`

Assigning values from a PHP array `array(1 => 'apple', 2 => 'banana' ... 27 => 'eggplant');` is going to use more overhead than a MySQL `SELECT` statement on a `VARCHAR` field, as well. Any performance you gain on the database side will be lost fivefold on the application side.

Comment: Readability in not my issue here, its somewhat correct but this will be one time job so i wont be reading the values but the server will do. Will i have any actual benefit on my resources?

Comment: @Incognito MySQL is a lot faster at performing `SELECT` than PHP will be on assigning strings via an int lookup in an array. Any performance you gain on SQL side will be lost fivefold on PHP side. (Though, you are right to think integer comparison is faster than string comparison)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, you are right it will be slower as the php will have to assign the values.

Answer (score 1):

Use VARCHAR.

Alternatively, if you are absolutely certain the products will stay static, you could use [ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html) to save some space, but there won't be much space to save on only 27 rows.

However, if you need to reference the products from other tables, consider creating a [surrogate key](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info) (auto-incrementing integer), to save space in the referencing tables (compared to repeating VARCHAR product names or 7-digit product IDs).

NOTE: To "save space" is not just about storage space - smaller data means less I/O and more effective caching with the given amount of RAM. This is not important for small tables, but can make a difference on large ones (e.g. if you have a big "order items" table that references products).

Comment: Yes Enum seems a better choice in my case as i see.